# How can I prevent key presses from changing the value of a scrollbar control?

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, scrollbar, keypress

I have a form with a user control that has a vscrollbar control. I would like to handle the user control's keypress event, but when I press the 'down arrow' key (for example), the keypress event isn't handled, and the vscrollbar's value increases instead. Other navigational keys behave this way as well.

I would like to have the vscrollbar stop 'overriding' my intention to raise the keypress event. I was thinking I could set the user control's keypreview property to true, but then I noticed it doesn't have one.

Comment: To clarify, the vscrollbar is a member of the user control's controls.

Comment: You probably have the `TabStop` set to true. Just open the properties window and set the `TabStop` property to `False` for your scrollbar. That should most likely correct the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at using the `KeyDown` or `PreviewKeyDown` event instead.

Comment: I didn't realize there was such a difference between KeyDown/Up and Keypress. You'd think the different arguments would give it away, but I can be braindead sometimes. Thanks!